# Site description has an extra "for" and missing capital letter

Tags: bug, status-completed, tour

Very minor, but still:

[image: screenshot]

The site description:

> For for those using, extending or developing emacs

Has several problems:

- There's an extra "for" at the beginning, of course.
- "Emacs" should be capitalized, as it is a proper noun.
- An Oxford comma would be nice ("extending, or developing"), although technically both ways are grammatically correct.

The longer description on the [tour page](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tour) and on the front page when not logged also needs to have “emacs” capitalized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good call - I have updated the site description.

Comment: Thanks. Could you capitalize Emacs in the tour page as well (and wherever else it might be lurking)?